# Approximation of motion about instantaneous center

Tags: classical-mechanics, rigid-body-dynamics

I am trying to do kinematic analysis of suspension.My doubt is that can i find Trajectory of my Suspension joints by rotating these points about the instantaneous center and again finding the new instantaneous center and iterating it so and so.
Is this approach correct and if not why?

Comment: I don't have enough details to be sure, but what you describe sounds a whole lot like numeric integration, which is at the heart of nearly every simulation out there.

Comment: Definitely, not enough information is given. Please provide a sketch and an example calculation step. Take a four-bar linkage, for example. Can you approximate its motion with a series of arcs? Yes and no. The instant center moves also, so the resulting curve may look nothing like an arc.

Answer (score 0):

I tried same approach as given in question and to validate my assumption i found the length of each link after every iteration.The results showed that There is negligible change in length of the links in suspension which shows that my assumption is reasonably valid.

Suspension type:- Double wishbone

My detailed approach:-
First i gave a co-ordinates of suspension points and time (say 1s) as input to the code. Using the initial geometry i found the instantaneous axis (using the approach as given in RACE CAR VEHICLE DYNAMICS Book by WILLIAM Milliken) and all the parameters(scrub radius , castor ,Kingpin inclination etc) and i rotated all points about the instantaneous axis for a short time(say 1/100s) with an angular velocity of 1 rad/s. So I got all parameters including wheel travel as a function of time and i could easily plot all parameters as a function of wheel travel. Since there was a negligible change in length of various arms ,So my assumption is reasonably valid and Dynamic analysis can be carried using this approximation.
**Other Methods to do it are WELCOME**

**HOPE THIS HELPS**